# MVC Entity Framework adding a int[] array list of categories to the view model

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, model, repository, entity

I'm trying to add a `int[]` array list of categories to the view `SelectedCategories` but getting the following error:

> base {System.SystemException} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32][] ToArray[Nullable`1](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Could anyone with experience with MVC Entity Framework please point out where I'm going wrong.

Code:

(View Model)

```
public class CandidateViewModel
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int? CandidateID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string CandidateName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("City")]
    public string CityName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Rate (Per Hour)")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")] 
    public System.Nullable<decimal> UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Start Date")]
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("End Date)")]
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public MultiSelectList CategoriesList { get; set; }

    public int?[] SelectedCategories { get; set; }
}



[Candidate Repository]
public IQueryable<CandidateViewModel> GetCandidatesProjected()
{
     var projectedCandidates = from p in GetCandidates()
                            select new CandidateViewModel
                            {

                                SchedulerID = p.id,
                                CandidateID = p.candidate_id,
                                StartDate = p.start_date,
                                EndDate = p.end_date,
                                SelectedCategories = p.Candidate.Candidate_Category.Where(a=>a.CandidateId==p.candidate_id).Select(b=>b.CategoryId).ToArray()

                            };

    return projectedCandidates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you need to change `Select(b=>b.CategoryId)` to `Select(b=>(int?)b.CategoryId)`, since currently you're selecting an `IEnumerable<int>` then converting to `int[]` and assigning to an `int?[]`.

Alternatively you could change `public int?[] SelectedCategories { get; set; }`to return either `int[]` or `IEnumerable<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Always use IEnumerable instead of arrays. Arrays already implement IEnumerable (I have friends programming for 5-6 years in C# that don't know that).
2. Whenever possible avoid nullable types. No selected item should be a NoSelectedItem special class, no items in a list should be an empty enumerable.
3. When getting data in your view model from a IQueryable result, call ToList() to force execution of the queries in your data layer.